# Show whether $\int_{0}^{\pi/2} \frac{\sqrt{\sin(x)}}{x}$ converges or diverges

Tags: real-analysis

The problem is stated as:

> Show whether $\int_{0}^{\pi/2} \frac{\sqrt{\sin(x)}}{x}$ converges or diverges using the comparision theorem.

So, I started solving the problem, thinking I'd get somewhere using this approximation $0\leq \sqrt{\sin(x)} \leq 1$, but I always end up in a situation where I have the integral greater than something and that thing converges, or in a situation where the integral is less than something, and that thing diverges. Which makes it impossible for me to use the comparision theorem.

Thank you for any tips.

Comment: Try the inequality $\sin x\le x$ for $x\ge0$.

Comment: @BarryCipra Omg how could I forget that haha. Thank you alot. Appreciated :)

Comment: The function $\phi:x\mapsto\sqrt{\sin x}{\sqrt{x}}$ for $x\neq0$ and $1$ for $x=1$ is continuous in $[0,\pi/2]$ and $|\phi(x)|\leq 1$. Hence $|\frac{\phi(x)}{\sqrt{x}}|\leq\frac{1}{\sqrt{x}}$. It is known that $x\mapsto\frac{1}{\sqrt{x}}$ is integrable in any interval of the form $[0,b]$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem being for $x$ close to $0$, use the series expansion
$$\sin(x)=x-\frac{x^3}{6}+O\left(x^5\right)$$
$$\sqrt{\sin(x)}=\sqrt{x}-\frac{x^{5/2}}{12}+O\left(x^{9/2}\right)$$
$$\frac 1 x\sqrt{\sin(x)}=\frac{1}{\sqrt{x}}-\frac{x^{3/2}}{12}+O\left(x^{7/2}\right)$$
$$\int\frac 1 x\sqrt{\sin(x)}\,dx=2 \sqrt{x}-\frac{x^{5/2}}{30}+O\left(x^{9/2}\right)$$

Just using the above, the value of the definite integral would be
$$\frac{240-\pi^2}{120} \sqrt{\frac{\pi }{2}}=2.40355$$ while the "exact" value would be $2.40459$.